# Error in reading ' (apostrophe) from text file into sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im doing bulk insert from a text file to the sql server, but im facing an error while reading the text file , this error is due to the presence of ' in text file, AS it is known that ' is used to indicate the start and end of string, please tell me how to iver come it.

sql query to insert data from text file is

```
  bulk insert #tmpfile from c:\data.txt with (firstrow=2,fieldterminator=':!:',rowtermintor='\n')
```

one of line in the text file where ' present is

```
32562 :!: saicahndan muriki, analyst,'belongs to development activities ------->facing error
```

Here I have no rights to edit the text file by placing one more apostrophe(') to escape, Please tell me what to do

Comment: what is the encoding of data.txt ?

Comment: @tschmit007, what is this about encoding

Comment: I try your sample with a file encoded as UTF16-LE and the bulk insert runs with or without '. (before it fails with an UTF8 encoded file)

Comment: @tschmit007, can u tell me how to fix it in the code

Comment: you need to know the encoding of data.txt to use the codepage option of [bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). You have to hope that the code page of data.txt is supported by sql server. For example UTF8 is not supported (really surprising indeed).

Comment: @tschmit007, my file is in ANSI encoding, please tell me, to which encoding i have to convert to make it as readable by ignoring erros, I have UCS-2 BIG ENDIAN, UCS-2 LITTLE ENDIAN, UTF-8 WITHOUT BALM encoding formats

Comment: try `codepage='1252'` or `codepage='850'`

Comment: If you can convert your file, the native of sql server is UCS-2 Little Endian

Comment: What error message do you get? What does the `#tmpfile` table look like (show the `CREATE TABLE` statement)? There is a spelling mistake in your SQL command, is that really the one you're using? Your fieldterminator says that the sample text file row you've shown is made up of only two columns, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

' is an escape character, if you do a search and replace on ' with '' (two single quotes) this will resolve your problem

Comment: ' is effectivelly an escape character for an tsql query, but imho not for a bulk insert

Comment: Its from a text file, so I would not be so sure, however you may be right.